# How do I horizontally center my Nav menu in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontally center my nav menu on my page, and I've tried text:align and margin:0 and display:inline, but nothing works. I think I know what the problem is though. I'm not actually trying to center the text in the blocks; I've already done that. I'm trying to center the blocks on the page so that they are a line straight across that is centered perfectly. As you can see my nav menu is not a line, but rather a series of blocks all enclosed within the same "ul" element. So my question is, how do I get the blocks to be horizontally centered perfectly on the page in a straight line?
I've put double asterix around the folder path from the Html to the Css document, so If you run it you can change that to where it is saved on your computer.

My CSS:

```
body {
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*vertical center*/
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Palatino, Georgia, Serif;
  color: #02849D;
  /*dark navy blue*/
  text-align: left;
  /*Personal Addition*/
  background-image: url('../Images/Black_Rainbow.jpg');
  background-size: 175% 100%;
  /*mess with*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*boxing, borders, and padding*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-width: 4px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #02849D;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 4px;
}

h2, h3 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
}
.box {
  /*a class tag that I use for my div elements, since I didn't want this to apply for all of my div elements I made a class so that I can easily state whether or not it should apply*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: #111111;
}

p {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 1em;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 0.35em;
}

table {
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

th {
  border: 0.15em solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:link {
  color: #31AEC5;
  /*dark blue*/
}

a:visited {
  color: #015261;
  /*darker blue*/
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #505050;
  /*grey*/
}

nav {
  clear: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.gamebutton {
  background-color: #707070;
  /*grey*/
  border: none;
  color: #02849D;
  /*bright blue*/
  width: 450px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  /*centers the text vertically*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  float: left;
}

.temp {
  font-style: italic;
}

#main {
  color: #008B8B;
  clear: left;
}

#overview {
  color: #7FFFD4;
}

#overview:first-letter {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
}

#DigDug {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}

#DigCaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 833.5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#BlockGame {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 550px;
  border-width: 0;
}

#skipnav {
  position: relative;
  right: 12.5%;
  width: 10.5em;
}


/* navigation menu styles */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.125em 0.5985243em;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* no underline */
  background-color: #55FA99;
  /* dark green */
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* rounded corner! */
  border-top-right-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* another rounded corner! */
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
  color: #014C65;
  background-color: #006E5F;
  /*medium green*/
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav_menu {
  border: 0;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" media="screen">
  <link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png">
  <title>Web Portfolio: Patrick White's Index Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
<div class="box" id="skipnav">
  <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
<h1>Patrick White Web Portfolio</h1>
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>Patrick White</li>
    <li><a href="mailto:TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com">TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com</a></li>
    <li>843-653-3474</li>
    <li>link to one of my favourite <a href="http://eelslap.com/" target="_blank">websites</a></li>
    <li>If you like goats, download my presentation! In either: <a href="Images/GOATS.pdf" download>PDF</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS_VIDEO.wmv" download>Video</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS.odp">Open Office</a> or <a href="Images/GOATS.ppt">Microsoft Powerpoint</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>I.T. 9 (1-2)</li>
    <li>Mr. Gabriel Jones</li>
    <li>Web Design</li>
    <li><a href="http://go.vsb.bc.ca/schools/pointgrey/Pages/Default.aspx" target="_blank">Point Grey Secondary</a>, 2016-2017</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav_menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Accesibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
      <li><a href="Usability.html">Usability</a></li>
      <li><a href="Graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="Tools.html">Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
      <li><a href="Games.html">Games</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div>
  <main id="main">
    <p id="overview">This web portfolio includes examples of my works in Mr. Jones' Web Design class. It also includes my reflections (below) in what I learned with each unit of the course.</p>
    <h2>Unit 2</h2>
    <p>In this section, I learned the basics of a fundamental scripting language for website design; <i>HTML5</i>. I learned about some of the many tags that are useful in the design of websites that will assist me in my prospective career in web design.
      In this unit I was presented with many resources to ensure that my HTML code was formatted correctly and was error-free, in the form of online generators. We also learned a great deal about how to incorporate links and images into our file, of which
      I found particularly interesting. In this section we learned a lot about how to input the actual content of our websites, and I am very excited for the future units in which we get to further design this content to seem visually appealing.</p>
    <h2>Unit 3</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 4</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 5</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 6</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 7</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
  </main>
</div>
<a href="http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-me-and-the-key" target="blank" class="gamebutton">Click to Play One of My Favourite Games!</a>
<!--Game Button-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving a `margin: 0 auto;` for your `<nav>` element or `.nav_menu` class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align: center;` to your `.nav-menu` class.

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `nav` element.

Explanation: `inline-block` makes your `nav` element only the size of its children instead of the full width of its parent. Then, centering the content of `.nav-menu` tells `.nav-menu` to center its children, including `nav`.

```css
/*CSS file - Patrick White*/

body {
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*vertical center*/
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Palatino, Georgia, Serif;
  color: #02849D;
  /*dark navy blue*/
  text-align: left;
  /*Personal Addition*/
  background-image: url('../Images/Black_Rainbow.jpg');
  background-size: 175% 100%;
  /*mess with*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*boxing, borders, and padding*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-width: 4px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #02849D;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 4px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.box {
  /*a class tag that I use for my div elements, since I didn't want this to apply for all of my div elements I made a class so that I can easily state whether or not it should apply*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: #111111;
}

p {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 1em;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 0.35em;
}

table {
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

th {
  border: 0.15em solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:link {
  color: #31AEC5;
  /*dark blue*/
}

a:visited {
  color: #015261;
  /*darker blue*/
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #505050;
  /*grey*/
}

nav {
  clear: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.gamebutton {
  background-color: #707070;
  /*grey*/
  border: none;
  color: #02849D;
  /*bright blue*/
  width: 450px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  /*centers the text vertically*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  float: left;
}

.temp {
  font-style: italic;
}

#main {
  color: #008B8B;
  clear: left;
}

#overview {
  color: #7FFFD4;
}

#overview:first-letter {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
}

#DigDug {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}

#DigCaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 833.5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#BlockGame {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 550px;
  border-width: 0;
}

#skipnav {
  position: relative;
  right: 12.5%;
  width: 10.5em;
}


/* navigation menu styles */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.125em 0.5985243em;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* no underline */
  background-color: #55FA99;
  /* dark green */
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* rounded corner! */
  border-top-right-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* another rounded corner! */
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
  color: #014C65;
  background-color: #006E5F;
  /*medium green*/
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav_menu {
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="skipnav">
  <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
<h1>Patrick White Web Portfolio</h1>
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>Patrick White</li>
    <li><a href="mailto:TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com">TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com</a></li>
    <li>843-653-3474</li>
    <li>link to one of my favourite <a href="http://eelslap.com/" target="_blank">websites</a></li>
    <li>If you like goats, download my presentation! In either: <a href="Images/GOATS.pdf" download>PDF</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS_VIDEO.wmv" download>Video</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS.odp">Open Office</a> or <a href="Images/GOATS.ppt">Microsoft Powerpoint</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>I.T. 9 (1-2)</li>
    <li>Mr. Gabriel Jones</li>
    <li>Web Design</li>
    <li><a href="http://go.vsb.bc.ca/schools/pointgrey/Pages/Default.aspx" target="_blank">Point Grey Secondary</a>, 2016-2017</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav_menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Accesibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
      <li><a href="Usability.html">Usability</a></li>
      <li><a href="Graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="Tools.html">Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
      <li><a href="Games.html">Games</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div>
  <main id="main">
    <p id="overview">This web portfolio includes examples of my works in Mr. Jones' Web Design class. It also includes my reflections (below) in what I learned with each unit of the course.</p>
    <h2>Unit 2</h2>
    <p>In this section, I learned the basics of a fundamental scripting language for website design; <i>HTML5</i>. I learned about some of the many tags that are useful in the design of websites that will assist me in my prospective career in web design.
      In this unit I was presented with many resources to ensure that my HTML code was formatted correctly and was error-free, in the form of online generators. We also learned a great deal about how to incorporate links and images into our file, of which
      I found particularly interesting. In this section we learned a lot about how to input the actual content of our websites, and I am very excited for the future units in which we get to further design this content to seem visually appealing.</p>
    <h2>Unit 3</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 4</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 5</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 6</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 7</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
  </main>
</div>
<a href="http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-me-and-the-key" target="blank" class="gamebutton">Click to Play One of My Favourite Games!</a>
<!--Game Button-->
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

In `nav ul li` add `display: inline-block;` instead of float. 
After that you can align it using `text-align` on `nav ul`.
Check updated snippet below:

```css
/*CSS file - Patrick White*/

body {
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*vertical center*/
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Palatino, Georgia, Serif;
  color: #02849D;
  /*dark navy blue*/
  text-align: left;
  /*Personal Addition*/
  background-image: url('../Images/Black_Rainbow.jpg');
  background-size: 175% 100%;
  /*mess with*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*boxing, borders, and padding*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-width: 4px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #02849D;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 4px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.box {
  /*a class tag that I use for my div elements, since I didn't want this to apply for all of my div elements I made a class so that I can easily state whether or not it should apply*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: #111111;
}

p {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 1em;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 0.35em;
}

table {
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

th {
  border: 0.15em solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:link {
  color: #31AEC5;
  /*dark blue*/
}

a:visited {
  color: #015261;
  /*darker blue*/
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #505050;
  /*grey*/
}

nav {
  clear: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.gamebutton {
  background-color: #707070;
  /*grey*/
  border: none;
  color: #02849D;
  /*bright blue*/
  width: 450px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  /*centers the text vertically*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  float: left;
}

.temp {
  font-style: italic;
}

#main {
  color: #008B8B;
  clear: left;
}

#overview {
  color: #7FFFD4;
}

#overview:first-letter {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
}

#DigDug {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}

#DigCaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 833.5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#BlockGame {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 550px;
  border-width: 0;
}

#skipnav {
  position: relative;
  right: 12.5%;
  width: 10.5em;
}


/* navigation menu styles */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.125em 0.5985243em;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* no underline */
  background-color: #55FA99;
  /* dark green */
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* rounded corner! */
  border-top-right-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* another rounded corner! */
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
  color: #014C65;
  background-color: #006E5F;
  /*medium green*/
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav_menu {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="skipnav">
  <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
<h1>Patrick White Web Portfolio</h1>
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>Patrick White</li>
    <li><a href="mailto:TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com">TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com</a></li>
    <li>843-653-3474</li>
    <li>link to one of my favourite <a href="http://eelslap.com/" target="_blank">websites</a></li>
    <li>If you like goats, download my presentation! In either: <a href="Images/GOATS.pdf" download>PDF</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS_VIDEO.wmv" download>Video</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS.odp">Open Office</a> or <a href="Images/GOATS.ppt">Microsoft Powerpoint</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>I.T. 9 (1-2)</li>
    <li>Mr. Gabriel Jones</li>
    <li>Web Design</li>
    <li><a href="http://go.vsb.bc.ca/schools/pointgrey/Pages/Default.aspx" target="_blank">Point Grey Secondary</a>, 2016-2017</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav_menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Accesibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
      <li><a href="Usability.html">Usability</a></li>
      <li><a href="Graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="Tools.html">Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
      <li><a href="Games.html">Games</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div>
  <main id="main">
    <p id="overview">This web portfolio includes examples of my works in Mr. Jones' Web Design class. It also includes my reflections (below) in what I learned with each unit of the course.</p>
    <h2>Unit 2</h2>
    <p>In this section, I learned the basics of a fundamental scripting language for website design; <i>HTML5</i>. I learned about some of the many tags that are useful in the design of websites that will assist me in my prospective career in web design.
      In this unit I was presented with many resources to ensure that my HTML code was formatted correctly and was error-free, in the form of online generators. We also learned a great deal about how to incorporate links and images into our file, of which
      I found particularly interesting. In this section we learned a lot about how to input the actual content of our websites, and I am very excited for the future units in which we get to further design this content to seem visually appealing.</p>
    <h2>Unit 3</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 4</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 5</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 6</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 7</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
  </main>
</div>
<a href="http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-me-and-the-key" target="blank" class="gamebutton">Click to Play One of My Favourite Games!</a>
<!--Game Button-->
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the  fixture:

Use `display:inline-block` on **nav li** and `text-align:center` on **nav ul** .. **This will solve the problem.**

```
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  text-align:center;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}

nav ul li {
 /* float: left;*/
  margin-right: 1em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
/*CSS file - Patrick White*/

body {
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*vertical center*/
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Palatino, Georgia, Serif;
  color: #02849D;
  /*dark navy blue*/
  text-align: left;
  /*Personal Addition*/
  background-image: url('../Images/Black_Rainbow.jpg');
  background-size: 175% 100%;
  /*mess with*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*boxing, borders, and padding*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-width: 4px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #02849D;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 4px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Rockwell, Baskerville, Warnock, Serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.box {
  /*a class tag that I use for my div elements, since I didn't want this to apply for all of my div elements I made a class so that I can easily state whether or not it should apply*/
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #006E5F;
  border-width: 3px;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: #111111;
}

p {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 1em;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0.35em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00594D;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin: 0.35em;
}

table {
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

th {
  border: 0.15em solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.35em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}

a:link {
  color: #31AEC5;
  /*dark blue*/
}

a:visited {
  color: #015261;
  /*darker blue*/
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #505050;
  /*grey*/
}

nav {
  clear: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.gamebutton {
  background-color: #707070;
  /*grey*/
  border: none;
  color: #02849D;
  /*bright blue*/
  width: 450px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  /*centers the text vertically*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  float: left;
}

.temp {
  font-style: italic;
}

#main {
  color: #008B8B;
  clear: left;
}

#overview {
  color: #7FFFD4;
}

#overview:first-letter {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
}

#DigDug {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0;
}

#DigCaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 833.5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#BlockGame {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 550px;
  border-width: 0;
}

#skipnav {
  position: relative;
  right: 12.5%;
  width: 10.5em;
}


/* navigation menu styles */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
  /* float: left;*/
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 0.125em 0.5985243em;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* no underline */
  background-color: #55FA99;
  /* dark green */
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* rounded corner! */
  border-top-right-radius: 1em 1em;
  /* another rounded corner! */
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:focus {
  color: #014C65;
  background-color: #006E5F;
  /*medium green*/
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav_menu {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="skipnav">
  <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
<h1>Patrick White Web Portfolio</h1>
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>Patrick White</li>
    <li><a href="mailto:TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com">TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com</a></li>
    <li>843-653-3474</li>
    <li>link to one of my favourite <a href="http://eelslap.com/" target="_blank">websites</a></li>
    <li>If you like goats, download my presentation! In either: <a href="Images/GOATS.pdf" download>PDF</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS_VIDEO.wmv" download>Video</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS.odp">Open Office</a> or <a href="Images/GOATS.ppt">Microsoft Powerpoint</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>I.T. 9 (1-2)</li>
    <li>Mr. Gabriel Jones</li>
    <li>Web Design</li>
    <li><a href="http://go.vsb.bc.ca/schools/pointgrey/Pages/Default.aspx" target="_blank">Point Grey Secondary</a>, 2016-2017</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav_menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Accesibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
      <li><a href="Usability.html">Usability</a></li>
      <li><a href="Graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="Tools.html">Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
      <li><a href="Games.html">Games</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div>
  <main id="main">
    <p id="overview">This web portfolio includes examples of my works in Mr. Jones' Web Design class. It also includes my reflections (below) in what I learned with each unit of the course.</p>
    <h2>Unit 2</h2>
    <p>In this section, I learned the basics of a fundamental scripting language for website design; <i>HTML5</i>. I learned about some of the many tags that are useful in the design of websites that will assist me in my prospective career in web design.
      In this unit I was presented with many resources to ensure that my HTML code was formatted correctly and was error-free, in the form of online generators. We also learned a great deal about how to incorporate links and images into our file, of which
      I found particularly interesting. In this section we learned a lot about how to input the actual content of our websites, and I am very excited for the future units in which we get to further design this content to seem visually appealing.</p>
    <h2>Unit 3</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 4</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 5</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 6</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
    <h2>Unit 7</h2>
    <p class="temp">This section will be completed soon</p>
  </main>
</div>
<a href="http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-me-and-the-key" target="blank" class="gamebutton">Click to Play One of My Favourite Games!</a>
<!--Game Button-->
```